# Itunesconnect interface has changes where are in app purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Itunesconnect has changed their interface, where are in app purchases?
When you connect you see pricing, but their is no link to in app purchases!

Answer (score 0):

```
**Features!** TAB
```

Click on that tab and you will see in-app-purchases! phew!

Answer (score 0):

My apps > Features > In-App Purchases

or, access directly https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/[YOUR_APP_ID]/addons

[image]